# Check if previous lines have same value in a specific column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create an auxiliary column with the following value:

- If column M is not empty, and column M of some previos line has same value -> 1
- Otherwise -> 0

Any simple way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it is about repeating the same value in any of the previous lines.
Then, you can use the formula:

```
=N(AND(M2<>"",COUNTIF(M$1:M1,M2)))
```

[image: Duplicates in M]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken and understood correctly, then one could use one of the followings as well:

• Using Fill Down Method:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N2</kbd>

```
=(COUNTIF(M$2:M2,M2)-1)*(M2>0)
```

---

Or, Using `LAMBDA()` helper to spill for the whole range:

```
=MAP(M2:M10,LAMBDA(α,(COUNTIF(M$2:α,α)-1)*(α>0)))
```

---

**Note:** Using `*` works as `AND()` function here.